# Android: How do I parse an HTML page?

Tags: android, sdk, html-parsing, android-webview

I new to android programming. I would like to know how to parse a webpage and extract specific content into a ListView. What is the easiest and best way to do it? Can someone show me an example using what's given below?

URL = "Something.com".

I want to extract the names of the cities and href link for each one.

[ann arbor](http://annarbor.org/) 
[battle creek](http://battlecreek.org/) 
[central michigan](http://centralmich.org/) 
[**detroit metro**](http://detroit.org/) 
[flint](http://flint.org/) 
[grand rapids](http://grandrapids.org/)

Thank you guys and sorry for asking this basic question.

Comment: learn how to use xml parsers. there are lot of examples available.

Comment: @AndroSelva i think he is talking about HTML content parsing !!

Comment: yeah but he is talking abt specific tags parsing. wouldn't xml parsing be better choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look the code below and let me know if you have any doubts and see this link it may help you

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-lazy-loading-images-and-text-in-listview-from-http-json-data/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // URL to the JSON data
        String strUrl = "ur url/countries";

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

        // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

            // Start parsing xml data
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }

            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "country"

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.tv_country};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                                   HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);


            }
        }
    }

             @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("flag",path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like http://jsoup.org/ to get the html content.

Then use something like

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

extract the urls.

then

:matches(regex): find elements whose text matches the specified regular expression; e.g. div:matches((?i)login)

do a regular expression for the url you are looking for.

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I did this once and luckily I found that code.
You would just have to give a call to this Intentservice from your activity
and you would need to specify the website name at the top ( in url variable )

```
    public class parser extends IntentService {

public String url="http://www.mywebsite.com";

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
//  shutdown();
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


private Timer t = new Timer();
byte[] buffer;


public timeCell() {
    super("name"); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  BufferedReader reader=null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new URL(url).openStream()));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = null;
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.v("line was ", line);  // printing is done here ;)


    }

    }
```